# Unable to get all the documents in an index in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm using Kibana's dev tool console and trying to get all the documents for an index.  However, I only get the partial result.

Say I have an index that has information about each US state (50 documents).  If I do this search in the devtool, I only get documents for NJ to WY. I can't get anything for AK to MS.

```
GET state_info/_search 
{
  "query" : {
      "match_all" : {}
   }
}
```

I tried setting the size to like 10000 still no avail - only from NJ to WY docs shows up.

```
GET state_info/_search 
{
  "size" : 10000,
  "query" : {
      "match_all" : {}
   }
}
```

However, there is a .net app with elastic client and it can see all the docs from AK to WY. If I use the documentID for the state of AK from the .net app and search in the devtool console, I see the document.

```
GET state_info/_doc/esfjxcjdjhfhghWinD
```

What am I missing?  why kibana's devtool console behaves differently?

Comment: How many documents in total are there in your index? By default, you get 10 results, if you set the size to 10000 (the default max), you'll get 10K documents, but if you have more documents, you need to scroll

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the `index.max_result_window` from 10k (default max) to some value that you need. Please note that it's not recommended to increase that number too much. But if it's a one time operation it's okay to do that.

```
PUT state_info/_settings
{
  "index.max_result_window": 100000
}
```

---

```
GET state_info/_search 
{
  "size" : 100000,
  "query" : {
      "match_all" : {}
   }
}
```

---

Note: Firstly you can test if the document exist with the following API call.

```
GET state_info/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "state": "AK"
    }
  }
}
```

> "state": your field name and "AK": your field value

To check how many documents exist in the index you can use the `_count` API call.

```
GET state_info/_count
```

Please note that your application can use another index. To check all indices you can create a query like the following.

```
GET _all/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "state": "AK"
    }
  }
}
```